# NSM Better Meta database error

Tags: meta, metadata

I'm using NSM Better Meta 1.1.3 with EE 2.7.2 . I'm trying add entry specific meta data, however when I use the tag: {exp:nsm_better_meta:template url_title="{segment_3}"} I get the error below.  It seems to the url_title part that's causing the issue, any other nsm_better_tag works just fine.

Any ideas?

Thanks,

```
Error Number: 1054

Unknown column 'exp_channel_titles.dst_enabled' in 'field list'

SELECT exp_members.screen_name   as e_author, exp_channel_titles.entry_id    as e_entry_id, exp_channel_titles.channel_id    as e_channel_id, exp_channel_titles.site_id     as e_site_id, exp_channel_titles.title  as e_title, exp_channel_titles.url_title    as e_url_title, exp_channel_titles.entry_date   as e_date_created, exp_channel_titles.edit_date     as e_date_modified, exp_channel_titles.expiration_date  as e_date_valid, exp_channel_titles.author_id   as e_author_id, exp_channel_titles.day  as e_day, exp_channel_titles.month  as e_month, exp_channel_titles.year     as e_year, exp_channel_titles.dst_enabled   as e_dst_enabled, exp_nsm_better_meta.language_id   as e_language, exp_nsm_better_meta.title    as meta_title, exp_nsm_better_meta.description  as meta_description, exp_nsm_better_meta.keywords   as meta_keywords, exp_nsm_better_meta.keywords_append_default   as meta_keywords_append_default, exp_nsm_better_meta.publisher  as meta_publisher, exp_nsm_better_meta.author   as meta_author, exp_nsm_better_meta.rights  as meta_rights, exp_nsm_better_meta.canonical_url   as meta_canonical_url, exp_nsm_better_meta.robots_index     as meta_robots_index, exp_nsm_better_meta.robots_follow     as meta_robots_follow, exp_nsm_better_meta.robots_archive   as meta_robots_archive, exp_nsm_better_meta.sitemap_include     as meta_sitemap_include, exp_nsm_better_meta.sitemap_change_frequency  as meta_sitemap_change_frequency, exp_nsm_better_meta.sitemap_priority   as meta_sitemap_priority, exp_nsm_better_meta.geo_region    as meta_geo_region, exp_nsm_better_meta.geo_placename   as meta_geo_placename, exp_nsm_better_meta.geo_latitude     as meta_geo_latitude, exp_nsm_better_meta.geo_longitude     as meta_geo_longitude FROM exp_channel_titles INNER JOIN exp_members ON exp_channel_titles.author_id = exp_members.member_id LEFT JOIN exp_nsm_better_meta ON exp_channel_titles.entry_id = exp_nsm_better_meta.entry_id WHERE (exp_channel_titles.url_title = 'about_us' AND exp_channel_titles.site_id = '1') AND ( exp_nsm_better_meta.language_id = 0 OR exp_nsm_better_meta.entry_default = 1 OR # NULL for entries that have no meta exp_nsm_better_meta.language_id IS NULL ) ORDER BY exp_nsm_better_meta.language_id DESC LIMIT 1

Filename: third_party/nsm_better_meta/mod.nsm_better_meta.php

Line Number: 205
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll definitely need to upgrade to [NSM Better Meta 1.1.5a](http://ee-garage.com/nsm-better-meta/release-notes#toc-v1_1_5a) - the release notes mention EE 2.6 compatibility, which likely includes accounting for the database changes which it brought (specifically, the removal of the `dst_enabled` column).

Comment: Hi Derek, thanks for help.  I've updated the plugin and it looks like that's fixed it.  Thanks again.